# $k$ times differentiable but not $C^k$ manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

I asked the following question on Math Stack Exchange 3 months ago but got no answer. So maybe Math Overflow is a more suitable place for such a question:

I cannot find the notion of $k$ times differentiable manifold with non-continuous $k^{th}$ differential, i.e. a manifold with charts having $k$ times differentiable transition maps, but where the $k^{th}$ differential of the transition maps are not continuous ($k \geq 1$).

Is there a reason for this ?

Does the theorem, saying the $C^k$ structure ($k \geq 1$) of a manifold is uniquely smoothable to a $C^\omega$ structure, apply to a differentiable but not $C^1$ manifold ?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz: But still the definition the OP suggests looks perfectly natural, and people often study structures that are suggested by such considerations rather than interesting concrete examples (are there "interesting" manifolds that are $C^{11}$, but not $C^{12}$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling That is ok.

Comment: These assumptions are usually forced by the known techniques and proofs. The question is just as relevant for functions on Euclidean space. Even if something holds for the more general class, it’s usually not worth the effort. That said, there’s a lot of work on Lipschitz structures.

Comment: Also, I believe that any $C^1$ manifold has a unique compatible smooth structure. This is not necessarily true for a Lipschitz manifold. I do not know what happens if the structure is differentiable but there is no bound on the derivatives of the transition functions.

Comment: Here's a naive answer, but can't one construct such a thing by gluing two copies of $\mathbb R^1$ along a function with these properties, say the $k$th antiderivative of a positive discontinuous map (positive so that so that the antiderivative will be increasing and so injective)?